# C program unexpectedly crashes after giving correct output

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, swap

I am trying to write a simple C program to reverse the string. The code is below:

```
void swap(char* a, char* b){
    char* temp;

    *temp  = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *temp;
}


char* reverseString(char* str){
    int length = strlen(str);
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<(length/2); i++){
            swap(&str[i], &str[length-i-1]);
    }

    return str;
}

int main(){
    char str[] = "Hello World";
    reverseString(str);
    printf("%s\n",str);

    return 0;
}
```

It does print the correct result but then it gives out a SEGMENTATION FAULT. It happens at the "return 0" statement of the main function.

Could you help me figure out why there is a SEG FAULT happening.

Thanks.

Comment: `char* temp;` shoud be `char temp;`

Answer (score 7):

In your `swap()` function, ask yourself:

```
void swap(char* a, char* b){
  char* temp;
```

**Q:** Where is `temp` pointing right now?
**A:** Unknown, possibly someplace dangerous.

```
*temp = *a;
```

And yet we just wrote something to that spot.

Instead, use a `char`:

```
void swap(char* a, char* b){
  char temp;

  temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning why you don't see the problem straight away: The code will "work", and use some unknown memory location to store your temp variables. However, when you return, you're giving control back to the C runtime, which now has your characters written over its address space. I'm guessing you overwrote a pointer, and the runtime is trying to access outside its address space. That's why you only see the fault after your code has finished.

Answer (score 2):

You invoke undefined behavior, that's why the code appears to be working, but it's not really working correctly, you have a problem here

```
void swap(char* a, char* b) {
    char *temp;

    *temp  = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *temp;
}
```

you declared `temp` as a `char` pointer and then you dereference it while it's an invalid pointer, the right way to do this would be

```
void swap(char* a, char* b) {
    char temp;

    temp  = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

and you can do this too

```
void swap(char* a, char* b) {
    char temp[1];

    *temp  = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *temp;
}
```

which doesn't make much sense, but would work, or you could even do it like this

```
void swap(char* a, char* b) {
    char *temp;

    temp = malloc(1);
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        *temp  = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = *temp;

        free(temp);
    }
}
```

which makes way less sense but also works, the point is to show you that to use the indirection operator `*`, the pointer must be valid.

So the reason your program was crashing was undefined behavior caused by an invalid pointer dereference.

Answer (score 0):

In the swap function, 
either use 
int temp;

```
void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

or set int *temp = NULL so that it is not pointing to unknown memory.

```
void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
   char *temp = NULL;
   *temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = *temp;
}
```

Comment: Your second swap example is going to cause a crash. You are dereferencing a null pointer specifically in *temp = *a

Comment: My bad. I shouldve allocated the memory. Thanks.